# SQL SERVER STUFF FUNCTION SCENARIO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server, I have a table like this:

```
Col-1    Col-2    Col-3
------------------------
A         123     25.13
A         456     67.00
A         789     81.89
```

I want output like this:

```
Col-1      Col-2            Col-3
-----------------------------------
A         123,456,789      174.02
```

Comment: explain the logic.

Comment: a combination of STUFF and SUM probably?

Comment: I want all A related info to be in a single row,followed by co1-2 as list,col-3 as SUM value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML` clause  with `STUFF()` function :

```
select co1, stuff( (select distinct ','+cast(t1.col2 as varchar(255)) 
                    from table t1 
                    where t1.col1 = t.col1
                    for xml path('')
                    ), 1, 1, ''
                 ) as col2, 
       sum(col3)
from table t
group by co1;
```

Comment: And as I'll often point out, all the *stuff* is doing here is trimming a comma off the start of the almost-finished string. To focus on this code and think that `STUFF` is the important part is to clearly misunderstand what this code does.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Data :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Col1 VARCHAR(1),
                 Col2 INT,
                 Col3 FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @T( Col1, Col2, Col3 )
VALUES  ('A',123,25.13),('A',456,67),('A',789,81.89)
```

Query :

```
;WITH Keys AS (SELECT Col1,
                      SUM(Col3) AS Col3
               FROM @T 
               GROUP BY Col1)
SELECT Keys.Col1,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( CONVERT (NVARCHAR(MAX),(SELECT T.Col2 AS A
        FROM @T AS T 
        WHERE T.Col1 = Keys.Col1
        FOR XML PATH(''))),'</A><A>',','),'<A>',''),'</A>','') AS Col2,

        Keys.Col3
FROM Keys
```

Result :

```
Col1    Col2          Col3
A       123,456,789   174.02
```

Comment: This is more efficient solution.